# Nif export - Normals shared problem

Tags: export, normals

Need help for an unsolvable problem.

I use Blender to edit a cycle frame from the Pro Cycling manager game (PCM).

File in PCM is a .nif. I can import in Blender with Niftool.
File is a scene with 5 groups, 2x front wheels, 1x rear wheel (dummy) and 2x frame, LOD groups from 2 sizes. Each LOD groups is done with 2 or 3 3D frames with different levels of details (vertices number).

There are animations and lot a small details to set.

My problem is when exporting my creation. In the .nif file, I need somethinf called "match groups", what is the "normals shared".

I use Nifskope to reaf nif file.

In the original .nif file of the game there is a line in the block NiTriShapeData called "Num Match Groups" with a value = to the number of vertices of the concerned frame (between 600 and 12000 depending on the frame). Then we can see the "match groups".

In my created / exported file, Num match groups = 0 and I have nothing in match groups.
If I change value for the number of vertices, I can do it, but nothing else change, no match groups filled.

I think something is missing in the Blender export / Blender file, but I cannot understand and find what is missing.

I hesitate to try an old version of Blender and Niftool, can this help?

Nothing is reporting on the Internet, no one use Nif for PCM, just Zoo Tycon or Skyrim, code is really different : /

Thx in advance for any help!